# C# visual studio 2017 help!, text box input to add to an url

Tags: c#, textbox, visual-studio-2017

I am working in C# VS 2017, added an image to form on click on which it goes to an url.
So not what I want to do is to add a text box next to my image so that the user can input his text in it and when the user clicks on the image he will be navigated to url+text
my code is

```
 private void pictureBox8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://my.adobeconnect.com");
    }
}
```

Example when user clicks on the image, the user will be navigated to "https://my.adobeconnect.com" and now when the user add a text lets say "help" then if he clicks on the image he should be navigated to "https://my.adobeconnect.com/help"

Comment: This is very basic C# maybe you should read the docs?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397491(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Put a `TextBox` on your form, I call it textBox then just:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://my.adobeconnect.com/" + textBox.Text);
```

As this is a bit ugly with multiple variables I tend to use `string.Format`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
    (string.Format("https://my.adobeconnect.com/{0}", textBox.Text));
```

Or with C# 6.0 you can use an interpolated string:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start($"https://my.adobeconnect.com/{textBox.Text}");
//Note the $
```

Comment: @RealCode If this answer worked out for you, please accept it.